# RegEx for matching characters in square brackets in bash

Tags: regex, string, bash, shell, githooks

I need to implement my regexp for some characters with square brackets: 
1) `[+]` for this 
2) `[*]` and for this 
3) `[+/*]` and for this 
4) `[*/+]` and for this

I made this on bash:

```
[root@testmachine5 ~]# echo "[+]" | egrep -o "^\[(\+|\*|\+/\*)\]"
[+]
[root@testmachine5 ~]# echo "[*]" | egrep -o "^\[(\+|\*|\+/\*)\]"
[*]
[root@testmachine5 ~]# echo "[+/*]" | egrep -o "^\[(\+|\*|\+/\*)\]"
[+/*]
[root@testmachine5 ~]# echo "[*/+]" | egrep -o "^\[(\+|\*|\+/\*)\]"
[root@testmachine5 ~]#
```

How you can see, it works, in first, second and third variants. But it does not work in last variant.

How do I solve this problem?

Comment: Because it wasn't written such to match it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the last statement you have to add another option to the [alternation](https://www.regular-expressions.info/alternation.html) for the reversed version to match. You can combine the first 2 options to a character class:

```
echo "[*/+]" | egrep -o "^\[([+*]|\+/\*|\*\/\+)\]"
                             ^^^^       ^^^^^^
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/fgYI6X/1) | [Bash demo](https://ideone.com/SJOWpM)

Answer (score 1):

Between square brackets match a `+` optionally followed by `/*`, or `*` optionally followed by `/+`.

```
$ egrep -o '\[(\+(/\*)?|\*(/\+)?)\]' <<EOF
[+]
[/]
[*]
[+/*]
[*/*]
[/+*]
[*/+]
EOF
[+]
[*]
[+/*]
[*/+]
```

Answer (score 1):

More generic regex:

```
lynx@bionic:~/$ echo "[*]..[*]..[+/*]..[*/+]" | egrep -o "\[([*/+]{1,3})\]"
[*]
[*]
[+/*]
[*/+]
```

Or that's way

```
lynx@bionic:~$ echo "[*/+]" | grep -Po "(?<=\[)([*/+]{1,3})(?=\])"
*/+
```

Comment: That also matches `[///]`, though.